# Selecting distinct substring values

Tags: t-sql, substring, distinct

I have a field that is similar to a MAC address in that the first part is a group ID and the second part is a serial number.  My field is alphanumeric and 5 digits in length, and the first 3 are the group ID.

I need a query that gives me all distinct group IDs and the first serial number lexicographically.  Here is sample data:

```
ID
-----
X4MCC
X4MEE
X4MFF
V21DD
8Z6BB
8Z6FF
```

Desired Output:

```
ID
-----
X4MCC
V21DD
8Z6BB
```

I know I can do `SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 3)` but I don't know how to get the first one lexicographically.

Comment: I would group by the similar group IDs and select the first one based on the row id.  Just a hint while I work on the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
   ID
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      ID,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 3) ORDER BY ID) AS rn
   FROM MyTable
   ) oops
WHERE
   rn = 1
```

Comment: This is telling me incorrect syntax near WHERE. I copied and pasted, then changed the field name and table to the real table... checked for typos and I don't see what I did wrong. If I just run the inner query it runs fine

Comment: @SupremeDud You need an alias on the derived table.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: oops, missed that in my haste. Thanks

Comment: @gbn You're welcome. And I really like your alias name. In a world (SO) where 80 percent of all table names are MyTable or YourTable a table alias `oops` is highly appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Another way which seems to have the same cost as the query by **gbn**:

```
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(id, 1, 3);
```